# python pyqt5 getting output every time i change the qlistwidget index

Tags: python, pyqt5

so basically I have 3 list widgets and the problem is that when I select a row in one list and I select another row in one of the other lists both of the lists have indexes above -1 (meaning they are both selected).
what I want them to do is that when I press another row on a different list, the first lists index to change back to -1 making the row from that list unselected.
in order to do that I need to get input every time I select a row from any list unless there are other options to solve this problem.
hope that wasn't too complicated to understand. any help or attempt to help will be much appreciated.
here is a picture of the problem:

[image: 1]

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `QListWidget` and have it emit a custom signal when the selection changes that emits the instance of the the widget as the parameter.

Then in the parent widget you could have a single slot that would deselect the other two list widgets that works for all three lists.

---

update

Based on the information provided in the comments, you actually don't need to subclass `QListWidget`, instead you can get the instance using the `currentItemChanged` signal since it emits the previously selected item and the item it has changed to as arguments.  Then using the `QListWidgetItem.listWidget()` method you can get the instance of the list that emitted the signal.

Here is an example:

```
class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.resize(500,500)
        self.lists = [QListWidget(parent=self) for _ in range(3)]
        for widget in self.lists:
            self.layout.addWidget(widget)
            for i in range(30):
                item = QListWidgetItem(type=0)
                item.setText(str(i))
                widget.insertItem(i, item)
            widget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.deselect)

    def deselect(self, new, old):
        if not new: return
        instance = new.listWidget()
        for widget in self.lists:
            if widget != instance:
                widget.setCurrentRow(-1)
```

Comment: Actually, the subclass is not necessary for this specific case: you can connect to `currentItemChanged` and get the "selected" list widget from the first argument's item using `item.listWidget()`. The only difference is that you must also check that `item` is not `None`, since `setCurrentRow(-1)` will still call `currentItemChanged()` with the selected argument set to `None` and the deselected with the previous selection. A suggestion: the name "deselect" might be counter intuitive, considering the argument; it should probably be something like "deselectOthers".

Comment: @musicamante  clever  I didn't even think of that

Comment: Note that your update is not entirely correct: the second argument (what you called "new") is the deselection, and you are not actually interested in that (since it's a de-selection, you don't need any action on any list widget); you should only care about the first ("old", which should actually be "new", since it's the *new current item*) and proceed in the deselection of the *other* widgets only if its not `None`. While your current implementation is not completely faulty (there's no recursion), doing the for loop for a deselection is pointless for what's required.

Comment: @musicamante Like that?

Comment: Now it's perfect! :-)

Comment: YES I did what was in the example and I worked. I would of never figured this out by myself. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to connect to the [`currentRowChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentRowChanged) signal of QListWidget.

If your window layout is purely in code, then connecting the signals will look like this:

```
self.listwidget1.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_listwidget1_currentRowChanged)
self.listwidget2.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_listwidget2_currentRowChanged)
self.listwidget2.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_listwidget3_currentRowChanged)
```

If you are using Qt Designer, then the connections are automatically done by pyuic. Then your methods for handling changes in your QListWidgets are:

```
def on_listwidget1_currentRowChanged(self, currentRow):
    <put your code here>

def on_listwidget2_currentRowChanged(self, currentRow):
    <put your code here>

def on_listwidget3_currentRowChanged(self, currentRow):
    <put your code here>
```